# Confusion with downcasting value in Swift

Tags: swift, casting

I have two arrays.

```
var searchedArray: NSMutableArray!
var libraryArray: NSMutableArray!
```

I'm trying to fix my searchBar functionality because it always shows nil(searchedArray = nil).
I've tried to downcast it in different ways but it doesn't work.
Here's the snippet.

```
let laMutableCopy = (downloadManager.libraryArray as NSArray).mutableCopy()
        searchedArray = laMutableCopy.filter{
            guard let dict = $0 as? Dictionary<String, Any> else {return false}
            guard let title = dict["title"] as? String else {return false}
            return title.range(of: searchText, options: [caseInsensitive, .anchored]) != nil
            } as? NSMutableArray
```

Comment: In Swift 3+, prefers Stuff over NSStuff, like `Array` instead of `NSArray`.
Have an issue? Start by not doing too much operations in a single line to debug. Isn't it a NSArray instead of a NSMutableArray?

Comment: Why are you using Objective-C arrays? And why are you are using forced optionals? And what is the meaning of "it doesn't work"?

Comment: This is not my project. I need to solve this problem with these arrays. "It doesn't work" means that in all situations "searchedArray" is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that would work:

```
var libraryArray = [
    ["title": "foo"],
    ["title": "bar"]
]

var filteredArray = libraryArray.filter{
    // your production code doesn't have to be like this, but when attempting to debug
    // its very helpful to break each cast out into its own assign to see where you
    // are failing
    guard let dict = $0 as? Dictionary<String, Any> else { return false }
    guard let title = dict["title"] as? String else { return false }
    return title.range(of: "fo", options: [.caseInsensitive, .anchored]) != nil
} as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>
```

The problem with your code is that you're casting the result of the `filter` (a swift `Array`) to an `NSMutableArray`. Swift arrays can be cast to `NSArray`, but they cannot be cast to `NSMutableArray` without constructing a copy like so:

```
(libraryArray as NSArray).mutableCopy()
```

Comment: Code above shows this error. Cannot assign value of type 'Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>?' to type 'NSMutableArray?', Insert ' as! NSMutableArray'.

Comment: Sam, stop working with Objective-C arrays. Use Swift arrays.